# Как обработать изменения фотографии и эталонной фотографии?

Tags: c++, python, машинное-обучение

Есть фотографии изображающие человеческие клетки.
Есть эталонная фотография, с полностью здоровой клеткой.
Также есть большой количество с клетками, на которых патологии.
С помощью каких библиотек можно делать анализ эталона и фотографий с патологиями.
При условии, что надо не только отличать патологии, но и классифицировать по патологиям.

Comment: первое что приходит на ум при словах «фотография» и «классифицировать» — OpenCV.

Comment: @Fat-Zer OpenCV можно научить такому?

Comment: просто «научить» «скормив много изображений» ни одну библиотеку нельзя... а вот построить систему распознавания с использованием инструментария из OpenCV для предобработки изображений/выделения характерных особенностей/классификации почти наверняка можно...

Comment: [Identifying Medical Diagnoses and Treatable Diseases by Image-Based Deep Learning](http://www.cell.com/cell/pdf/S0092-8674(18)30154-5.pdf)